# On Minecraft vanilla server, it is possible to run a shell command when a specific user (or any user) logs in?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Running Minecraft 1.8.1 on Debian Wheezy. Any quick and easy way to call an event, or is there a callback I can hook into for when users log in to the server?

Comment: thanks @SevenSidedDie - I figured I could just watch the logs via a UNIX shell command but wondered if there was an event dispatched on login.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood it as a more general "is this possible" rather than specifically about whether MC has native support for it; in that case, my comment really should be an answer and I've added it below. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minecraft for PC doesn't provide such a native facility (though Minecraft for the Raspberry Pi does, with its integrated Python interpreter).

To do this, you can use pipe redirection with a log watcher or launch the server within a command wrapper that offers this kind of function. There are many options for this kind of functionality — none that are gaming specific — that you might already know about if you are familiar with *nix system administration, but if not [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) is likely the best source of further information.